# hang shutting down our Java 6 application, due to WToolkit.shutdown() not completing?

Tags: java, windows

The automated crash reporter in our application sometimes reports hangs when shutting the application down.  We have not observed this in house.  The swing thread hangs in ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks() and I think it could be because WToolkit.shutdown() never returns.  I don't know what is causing that though.  Can anyone help me out with what is causing the hang? Here is a complete thread dump. Thanks! The JRE is 1.6.0_35.

```
    Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.application.ISeekFrame$11$2.run(ISeekFrame.java:555)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Hang Watcher,10,main] RUNNABLE :
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source)
    at com.biomatters.utilities.HangWatcher.getAllThreadStackTraces(HangWatcher.java:77)
    at com.biomatters.geneious.common.talkback.client.TalkbackIncidentFactory.fieldsForHang(TalkbackIncidentFactory.java:437)
    at com.biomatters.geneious.common.talkback.client.TalkbackIncidentFactory.forHang(TalkbackIncidentFactory.java:186)
    at com.biomatters.geneious.common.ErrorUtilities.handleHang(ErrorUtilities.java:78)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.application.ISeekMain$16.handleHang(ISeekMain.java:1091)
    at com.biomatters.utilities.HangWatcher$2.run(HangWatcher.java:59)

    Thread[Exe4JStartupThread,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.exe4j.Controller$StartupThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[GarbageCollectionNotifier,6,main] WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.biomatters.geneious.publicapi.utilities.GarbageCollectionNotifier$1.run(GarbageCollectionNotifier.java:49)

    Thread[Biomatters-Timer-Thread,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.license.TimerThread.run(TimerThread.java:49)

    Thread[Thread-1,6,system] RUNNABLE :
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.shutdown(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system] RUNNABLE :

    Thread[TimerQueue,5,system] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.postExpiredTimers(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[main,5,main] RUNNABLE :

    Thread[AWT-Windows,6,main] RUNNABLE :
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Timer: UpdatingProperties - customBlast.properties,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Reference Handler,10,system] WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Biomatters-Timer-Thread,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.license.TimerThread.run(TimerThread.java:49)

    Thread[AWT-Shutdown,5,main] WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Multicast Reader,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.license.concurrentlicensechecker.Multicast$1.run(Multicast.java:150)

    Thread[Finalizer,8,system] WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Java2D Disposer,10,system] BLOCKED :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Do exit,6,main] BLOCKED :
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
    at com.biomatters.iseek.application.ISeekFrame$11.run(ISeekFrame.java:560)

    Thread[Memory Monitor,1,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.biomatters.utilities.MemoryMonitor$1.run(MemoryMonitor.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Timer: refresh plugin licenses,5,main] TIMED_WAITING :
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

    Thread[Attach Listener,5,system] RUNNABLE :
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, as does the JConsole program that is deployed with the JDK.  I am searching for a solution or bug report on this, but it is a regression that started with 1.6.0_25.  The problem does not happen on previous versions (I use 1.6.0_23 successfully).

This forum post is where I found this workaround:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2260059